# Storing files on the API or on the microservice filesystem

Tags: file-upload, upload, microservices, api-design

I work on an app that consists of a

- Frontend app
- API, that I like to think of as a gateway
- Microservices that handle the business logic and db work

Upon implementing a file store-like feature, for uploading *both small and large files*, I just assumed that I'd store these files on the microservice's filesystem and save paths, along with metadata, into the microservice's database.

Because the microservices don't implement any Http API endpoints, I upload files over my API gateway. But after realizing how much work must go into transferring these files from the API to the microservice, as well as serving the same back, I just went with storing them on the API's file system and saving the paths into the microservice's database.

---

Is this approach ok?

Is it weird that my API *gateway* stores and serves files from it's own file system?
If so, should I transfer the files from the API to the microservice, upon an upload, even considering the files can be large - or should the microservice implement a specific API itself?

I hope this question doesn't get interpreted as opinion-based - I'd like to know what approach would be best considering the frontend-api-microservice pattern and if there are any architecture standards that address this scenario, and also if any approach has it's *gotchas*.

Comment: just wondering why microservices don't have their endpoint? it should be microservice handling file upload

Comment: So it would be fine if a microservice handles both db work and fileupload? Could you please share more info? Maybe a link/reference aswell?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some time and some experience, the right answer to this question would be API Gateway. Microservices are complex enough on their own, and storing any files, small or large, would rather be a waste of networking, bandwith etc. and would just introduce latency issues and degrade performance as well as UX.

I'll leave this out here just so people can hear this, as neither approach would be wrong, while the API Gateway choice just provides more practical benefits and thus is more appropriate. If this question was targetting data or files that are stored within a DB, microservice and it's DB would be the obvious choice.

If you have the convenience to add an file server to your whole stack, then sure, that would be the correct approach, but that as well introduces more complexity and other stuff described above.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments above

**API Gateway**

The purpose of gateway is to redirect the requests and handle cross cutting concerns like authentication , logging etc. It shouldn't be doing more than that. Gateway has to be highly available and any problem to gateway means you can't access associated services.

**File Upload**

The file upload should be handled by microservice itself. Your gateway will only be used to pass and get the stream. Depending on nature of your system and if you are using cloud store you can use of pattern like "valet key". 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/valet-key